# Entity can still be selected after deleted all of the data in the table by mybatis in same transaction

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-transactions

#### 1.Development environment:

IDEA,ORACLE 12g,Mybatis

#### 2.The code where has this question

```java
 @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class,propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED )
    @Override public void syncSmartGateOrgList() {
        log.debug("syncSmartGateOrgList() called");
        //remove all of the current data if it's debug
        if (GlobalProperties.isDebug()) {
            int deleteLocalOrgResults = mSmartGateOrgServiceI.getDao().deleteByEntity(SmartGateOrg.builder().build());
            log.info("syncSmartGateOrgList deleteLocalOrgResults = " + deleteLocalOrgResults);
        }
        //validate params
        ValidateParams validateParams = SmartGateSignTool.getValidateParams(SmartGateConstants.getPlatformToken());
        log.info("syncSmartGateOrgList validateParams = " + validateParams);
        //get org list
        OrganizationResult organizationList = mSmartGateManager.getOrganizationList(SmartGateBody.builder().unitid(SmartGateConstants.getPlatformUnitId()).build(), validateParams.getSignature(), validateParams.getTimestamp(), validateParams.getNonce());

        //then import the data to the db
        if (Objects.equals(organizationList.getErrmsg(), OK)) {
            List<OrganizationResult.UnitsBean> units = organizationList.getUnits();
            log.info("syncSmartGateOrgList origin units = " + units.size());
            List<SmartGateOrg> collect = units.parallelStream().map(unitsBean -> {
                SmartGateOrg smartGateOrg = new SmartGateOrg();
                smartGateOrg.setUnitName(unitsBean.getUnitname());
                smartGateOrg.setUnitId(unitsBean.getUnitid());
                String unitPath = Joiner.on(",").join(unitsBean.getUnitpath());
                smartGateOrg.setUnitPath(unitPath);
                List<OrganizationResult.UnitsBean.ParentunitsBean> parentunits = unitsBean.getParentunits();
                smartGateOrg.setParentId(!Emptys.isEmpty(parentunits) ? parentunits.get(0).getUnitid() : "");
                smartGateOrg.setParentOrder(!Emptys.isEmpty(parentunits) ? String.valueOf(parentunits.get(0).getOrder()) : "");
                smartGateOrg.setParentPriority(!Emptys.isEmpty(parentunits) ? String.valueOf(parentunits.get(0).getPriority()) : "");
                smartGateOrg.setGovWxId(!Emptys.isEmpty(Optional.ofNullable(unitsBean.getExtend()).map(OrganizationResult.UnitsBean.ExtendBean::getWeworkpartyid)) ? String.valueOf(unitsBean.getExtend().getWeworkpartyid().get(0)) : "");
                smartGateOrg.setDeptType(!Emptys.isEmpty(unitsBean.getSystemtype()) ? unitsBean.getSystemtype().get(0) : "");
                smartGateOrg.setCreateBy("timer");
                return smartGateOrg;
            })
                    //check the data if it's existed before insert
                    .filter(smartGateOrg ->{
                        //fixme the data still could be found whatever the all of the data have been delete on the above
                        SmartGateOrg localEntity = mSmartGateOrgServiceI.getByEntity(SmartGateOrg.builder().unitId(smartGateOrg.getUnitId()).build());
//                        SmartGateOrg localEntity = mSmartGateOrgServiceI.getDao().selectOne(SmartGateOrg.builder().unitId(smartGateOrg.getUnitId()).build());
                        boolean aNull = Objects.isNull(localEntity);
                        if (!aNull) {
                            log.info("syncSmartGateOrgList localEntity = " + localEntity);
                        }
                        log.info("syncSmartGateOrgList aNull = " + aNull);
                        return aNull;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            log.info("syncSmartGateOrgList after filter units = " + collect.size());
            if (Emptys.isNotEmpty(collect)) {
                int result = mSmartGateOrgServiceI.addBatch(collect);
                log.info("syncSmartGateOrgList() returned: " + result);
            }
        } else {
            log.warn("syncSmartGateOrgList organizationList = " + organizationList);
        }

    }
```

#### 3.The sql which be used here:

```sql
    <!--delete data by condition-->
  <delete id="deleteByEntity">
        delete from T_SMART_GATE_ORG
        <where>
            <include refid="whereConditionFull"/>
        </where>
    </delete>
    <!--get entity by condition-->
<select id="getByEntity" resultMap="SmartGateOrgResultMap"
            parameterType="com.zx.lodging.modules.pojo.entity.smartgate.SmartGateOrg" >
        select
        <include refid="table_field"/>
        from T_SMART_GATE_ORG
        <where>
            <include refid="whereConditionFull"/>
        </where>
    </select>
```

#### 4.The issues:

a.first, the all data actually be deleted in this transaction becasue of the result returned was expected

b. not all of the data could still be found,most of the data was not found,and some of the data was still could be found.that's the problem is.

c. the question sql was actually executed and return nothing.The problem is that the 'selected' on the code still returns the data.I don't know if it's the cache problem

Comment: Was the transaction committed?

Comment: @The Impaler 
Obviously, when this problem occurs, the transaction of the entire method is not committed

Answer (score 1):

After I have debug for a while,I found this question was cause by the parallelStream where from the java1.8.I'm not sure what the root cause for this question.

But when I replace the parallelStream with **"stream" or "parallelStream.sequential"**,this problem is solved.